# How to traverse a trie to display all the words?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, trie

Here's my declaration of a trie in C++ using unordered_map

```
class trie{
    public:
    unordered_map<char,trie*>m;
    bool isEnd;
};
```

Here's my insert function(part of another class)

```
 trie *root=nullptr;
    trie *getNode()
    {
        trie *tmp=new trie();
        tmp->isEnd=false;
        return tmp;
    }
    void insert(string s)
    {
        if(!root)
            root=getNode();
    trie *tmp=root;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(tmp->m.find(s[i])==tmp->m.end())
            tmp->m[s[i]]=getNode();
        tmp=tmp->m[s[i]];
    } 
    tmp->isEnd=true;
    }
```

How to traverse this trie recursively or iteratively to display all the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void iterate_(const trie* node, const std::string& prefix) {
  if (node->isEnd) {
    std::cout << prefix << std::endl;
  }
  for (const auto& [c, child] : node->m) {
    iterate_(child, prefix + c);
  }
}

void iterate() {
  if (root) {
    iterate_(root, "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful. It was nice of you to help the OP cheat on his homework, but actually explaining the code would go a long way towards making this answer broadly useful.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me understand where I was gooing wrong

Comment: @Sneftel actually I was solving this problem in Leetcode : [link] (https://leetcode.com/problems/search-suggestions-system/) and was wondering how to traverse my trie recursively. 
i was using a for loop ```for(auto i=node->m.begin();i!=node->m.end();i++)```. This was displaying the characters in an incorrect order so I ddidnt know where I was wrong